# How to create regions in an aspx file?

Tags: asp.net

I wonder is there any way we can create regions in aspx page as we create it in our cs pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not as Expandable, but in HTML it is normal to use the comments in order to create blocks of code

```
<!-- Start: Login access form -->

... Code ...

<!-- End: Login access form -->
```

Comment: I don't think that really answers the question. The accurate answer would be "No." Not downvoting, though.

Comment: it does answer it, since the first three words are "not as Expandable", but it creates Regions of code. That is my opinion and that's why I answered.

Comment: That is adding comments, not creating a region and so doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no (at least not in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 3):

You can select the commented section, then right click, collapse tag.

Comment: I'm not understanding why this was down voted. It is essentially the best answer to this question. Simply highlight what you want to be collapsed, right click the selection, and click "Collapse Tag". You may also highlight a selection and press Ctrl+M, Ctrl+T. This way, no odd div's/hacks are being used. The IDE has this built right in.

Comment: Because "collapse tag" only collapses *existing* regions, while the OP asked for a way to *create* regions (for collapsing)! Obviously, the first approach only works if an existing region covers the area you want to collapse.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to do this.

However, I would suggest that if you are feeling the need to do this because your .aspx pages are very large, you might should look at redesigning it, or breaking it apart into User Controls (.ascx) or figure out a more effective use of master pages.

Not sure if that's the reason behind your question, but if it is, it's just a thought to pass on.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Visual Studio (could be the web essentials plugin, I can't remember if its native), the following snippet will be expandable in HTML files (including CSHTML). Unfortunately, these are not expandable in ASPX or ASCX files.

```
<!--#region Example -->

...code...

<!--#endregion Example -->
```

In an ASPX or ASCX file, perhaps you'd rather want to go with this:

```
<%-- START Example --%>

...code...

<%-- END Example --%>
```

They're still not expandable, but those will not get rendered out and therefore not be visible when right clicking on the page and viewing Source Code. You'll only see them in the development file.

P.S.
I didn't realize how old this question was until I finished typing out my answer. So I'm just going to go ahead and put this here anyway since it looks like it could use an update.

Comment: Thanks for the update, actually. I was wondering if things have changed since the question was asked -- A lot happens in 5-6 years.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio does a pretty good job of identifying elements with a significant amount of content to make it collapsable dynamically but thats the closest you going to get.

It might occur to you to place a series of element sibling in a DIV so that the div can be collapsed in visual studio.  Thats very tempting but I would advise against it.

Answer (score 1):

Regions are an IDE convenience that allow you to name a segment of code that may span multiple functions or procedures and be able to collapse/expand the whole segment as a whole. Visual Studio provides this feature only for code and **not** for HTML/ASPX/CSS portions of a file. For instance, you can create Regions within the <script runat="server"> section of an ASPX file.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Prof. 2022 V17.6.5 / .net Framework 4.7

This worked for me:

```
<% #region region1 %> 
<div>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeader" Text="Hello world" /> 
</div>
<% #endregion %>
```

BUT:

unfortunately the regions are always expanded after the file opened.

Answer (score -7):

You could use a div and put everything inside it

Comment: though posiibly not a good way, `<div id="Div_Region" style="display: none;">` maybe works